# How to resolve ImageIcon issue in flutter

Tags: flutter

Trying to set image for icon in flutter but not working. So, How to set path for ImageIcon in ListTile.

This line is not working:

> ```
> leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('images/abt.png'), size: 25),
> ```

```
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: ()
            {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> AboutScreen()));
            },
            child: const ListTile(
              tileColor: Colors.blue,
              leading: ImageIcon(AssetImage('images/abt.png'), size: 25),
              title: Text(
                "About",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
assets:  
    - images/
    - images/abt.png
```

Flutter uses the pubspec.yaml file, located at the root of your project, to identify assets required by an app. Read here how to  [specify assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly have not uncommented these lines in `pubspec.yaml`

```
# assets:
#  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
#  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```